# Finding an equation for a growth formula

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, trees

Given a tree that has three nodes each level I want to find the formula that predicts the number of all nodes with a given tree height.

[image]

I fitted the data into Numbers with an exponential function and it gave me a numeric formula:

[image]

But I'd like to know how to derive a non-numeric (calculus type) formula for this. What I did was finding out the growth formula

```
y(t) = a * e^(kt)
```

where

```
a = initial value
y = value after time/steps 
k = growth factor
t = time (or step)
```

But fitting my data into this formula doesn't give right predictions. For example:

```
a = 1
t = 4
y(t) = 40
```

Solving for k in step 4 (t=4):

```
(1) 40 = 1 * e^(4k)
(2) ln(40) = 4k
(3) k = ln(40) / 4 = 0.9222
```

Predicting number of all nodes in step 5 (t=5):

```
(4) y(5) = e^(0.9222*5) = 12.53
```

The answer is wrong because the tree has at 5th step already 121 nodes.

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to calculate this?

Thanks. Pom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following equation is suitable for growth
$$\frac{3^k-1}{2}$$
where $k$ is the number of the steps.

Comment: Great, thanks, that works! Is there a process for coming to this formula or did you just "see" it? :)

Comment: A little wolfram :) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2C+4%2C+13%2C+40%2C+121%2C+364%2C+...

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong choosing such kind of formula as desired one. However correct form is $y(t) = a\cdot e^{kt} + b$, but your way of getting formula by doing computation experiment in this case seems to be bad idea. It would be better to read about [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).

Comment: Good tip, thanks a lot.